# How should PHP's Iterator methods valid(), current(), and next() behave?

Tags: php

I am using PHP 5.3.6 from [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info).

I have a use case where it would be best to use PHP's `Iterator` interface methods, `next()`, `current()`, and `valid()` to iterate through a collection. A `foreach` loop will NOT work for me in my particular situation. A simplified while loop might look like

```
<?php
while ($iter->valid()) {
  // do something with $iter->current()
  $iter->next();
}
```

Should the above code always work when $iter implements PHP's `Iterator` interface? How does PHP's `foreach` keyword deal with Iterators?

The reason I ask is that the code I am writing may be given an `ArrayIterator` or a `MongoCursor`. Both implement PHP's `Iterator` interface but they behave differently. I would like to know if there is a bug in PHP or PHP's Mongo extension.

`ArrayIterator::valid()` returns true *before* any call to `next()` -- immediately after the `ArrayIterator` is created.

`MongoCursor::valid()` only returns true *after* the first call to `next()`. Therefore the while loop above will never execute.

At risk of being verbose, the following code demonstrates these assertions:

```
<?php

// Set up array iterator
$arr = array("first");
$iter = new \ArrayIterator($arr);

// Test array iterator
echo(($iter->valid() ? "true" : "false")."\n"); // Echoes true
var_dump($iter->current()."\n");                // "first"
$iter->next();
echo(($iter->valid() ? "true" : "false")."\n"); // Echoes false


// Set up mongo iterator
$m = new \Mongo();
$collection = $m->selectDB("iterTest")->selectCollection("mystuff");
$collection->drop(); // Ensure collection is empty
$collection->insert(array('a' => 'b'));
$miter = $collection->find(); // should find one object

// Test mongo iterator
echo(($miter->valid() ? "true" : "false")."\n"); // Echoes false

$miter->next();

echo(($miter->valid() ? "true" : "false")."\n"); // Echoes true
var_dump($miter->current());                     // Array(...)
```

Which implementation is correct? I found little documentation to support either behavior, and the official PHP documentation is either ambiguous or I'm reading it wrong. The [doc for](http://www.php.net/manual/en/iterator.valid.php) `Iterator::valid()` states:

> This method is called after Iterator::rewind() and Iterator::next() to check if the current position is valid.

This would suggest that my while loop should *first* call `next()`.

Yet the [PHP documentation for](http://www.php.net/manual/en/iterator.next.php) `Iterator::next` states:

> This method is called after each foreach loop.

This would suggest that my while loop is correct as written.

To summarize - how should PHP iterators behave?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an interesting question. I'm not sure why a `foreach` won't work for you, but I have some ideas.

Take a look at the example given on [the Iterator interface reference page](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). It shows the order in which PHP's *internal* implementation of `foreach` calls the `Iterator` methods. In particular, notice that when the `foreach` is first set up, the very first call is to `rewind()`. This example, though it's not well-annotated, is the basis for my answer.

I'm not sure why a `MongoCursor` would not return true for `valid()` until *after* `next()` is called, but you should be able to reset either type of object by calling `rewind()` prior to your loop. So you would have:

```
// $iter may be either MongoCursor or ArrayIterator

$iter->rewind();
while( $iter->valid() ){
    // do something with $iter->current()
    $iter->next();
}
```

I believe this should work for you. If it does not, the Mongo class may have a bug in it.

Edit: Mike Purcell's answer correctly calls out that ArrayIterator and Iterator are not the same. However, ArrayIterator implements Iterator, so you should be able to use `rewind()` as I show above on either of them.

Comment: This is a good approach as well, to rewind the iterator so ANY iterator instance will behave correctly when `valid()` is called. Due to inheritance, ArrayIterator's `valid` will supersede Iterator's version.

Comment: Calling `rewind()` on the MongoIterator does make it behave like the ArrayIterator. Thank you! (I am not used to an interface's behavior being defined only in documentation examples.)

Answer (score 8):

Subclassing any Iterator and echo'ing when it's called will tell you how it behaves.

#### Example ([demo](http://codepad.org/C0DdlEp8))

```
class MyArrayIterator extends ArrayIterator
{
    public function __construct ($array)
    {
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
        parent::__construct($array);
    }
    …
}

foreach (new MyArrayIterator(range(1,3)) as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k => $v", PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Output

```
MyArrayIterator::__construct
MyArrayIterator::rewind
MyArrayIterator::valid
MyArrayIterator::current
MyArrayIterator::key
0 => 1
MyArrayIterator::next
MyArrayIterator::valid
MyArrayIterator::current
MyArrayIterator::key
1 => 2
MyArrayIterator::next
MyArrayIterator::valid
MyArrayIterator::current
MyArrayIterator::key
2 => 3
MyArrayIterator::next
MyArrayIterator::valid
```

This is equivalent to doing

```
$iterator = new MyArrayIterator(range(1,3));
for ($iterator->rewind(); $iterator->valid(); $iterator->next()) {
    echo "{$iterator->key()} => {$iterator->current()}", PHP_EOL;
}
```

The sequence in which the methods are called is identical to a custom `Iterator`:

```
class MyIterator implements Iterator
{
    protected $iterations = 0;
    public function current()
    {
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
        return $this->iterations;
    }
    public function key ()
    {
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
        return $this->iterations;
    }
    public function next ()
    {
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
        return $this->iterations++;
    }
    public function rewind ()
    {
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
        return $this->iterations = 0;
    }
    public function valid ()
    {
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
        return $this->iterations < 3;
    }
}
foreach (new MyIterator as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k => $v", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you may have mixed up Iterator and ArrayIterator, as each has their own `valid()` api call.

- [Array Iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.valid.php) : There is no specific mention to `next()` etc, but the example clearly demonstrates what you mentioned in your OP, to paraphrase; that no other AI api call needs to be made to determine if current element of array is valid.
- [Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/iterator.valid.php) : As you mention: "This method is called after Iterator::rewind() and Iterator::next() to check if the current position is valid."

As such, I would stick with ArrayIterator, as it demonstrates the most correct behavior, in that `valid()` will correctly determine if current element in array is valid, without having to make another api call (next, rewind).

If you want get Mongo to behave like AI does, you could add an instance check before starting the while loop:

```
if ($iter instanceof MongoCursor) {
   $iter->next()
}

while ($iter->valid()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: While checking the class of the iterator would certainly work, the whole point of using an interface is that the code does not have to know or check the actual class of the object. The interface implies that certain behavior can be expected of any implementation. I was confused about what that behavior should be for `Iterator`.

Comment: "I was confused about what that behavior should be for Iterator", but your code snippet was using ArrayIterator.